# Value is always like it was before and not what is in the database

Tags: c#, linq

I use LINQ in ASP.NET and have a code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    IPost post = _postRepository.GetById(1);
    txtTest.Text = post.Title; 
    post.Title = "test" + i.ToString();
}
```

In each iteration I track the `post.Title`, but its value is previous value not what is in the database:

```
txtTest.Text:
    i=0 => what is in database
    i=1 => test0
    i=2 => test1
```

I have a post class:

```
public class Post
{
    Long Id { get; set; }

    long Author { get; set; }

    string Title { get;  set; }

    string Excerpt { get; set; }

    string Content { get; set; }        

    ICollection<ShareLink> ShareLinks
    {
        get
        {
            IShareLinkRepository _shareLinkRepository = null;
            _shareLinkRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IShareLinkRepository>();

            ICollection<ShareLink> shareLInks =_shareLinkRepository.Get();

            foreach (IShareLink shareLink in shareLInks)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
                string newUrl = context.Request.Url.Scheme +
                    "://" + context.Request.Url.Authority +
                    context.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/posts.aspx?p="
                    + this.Id;

                url.Replace("{title}", this.Tilte).Replace("{url}", newUrl);

            }

            return shareLInks;
        }
    }
}
```

and `ShareLink` is:

```
public class ShareLink     
{
    long Id { get; set; }

    string Url { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    string Image { get; set; }
}
```

the value for `ShareLink.url` is like this: `http://example.com/submit?phase=2&url={url}&title={title}`.

In the `ShareLinks` field of post class the all value of `ShareLinks.url` is first post `ShareLinks` value.

Comment: So, where exactly is *LINQ* used here?

Comment: This code does not make any sense to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
IPost post = _postRepository.GetById(1)
```

to

```
IPost post = _postRepository.GetById(i+1);
```

(Added as per below comments)

```
IPost newPost = new IPost();  // OR however you have managed to get your existing object

IEnumerable<IPost> allPosts = _postRepository.All();

foreach ( var post in allPosts)
{
     post.Url = String.Format("digg.com/submit?phase=2&url={0}&title={1}", newPost.Url, newPost.Title);
     post.Save();
}
```

Comment: still doesn't explain why he does get "test" instead of the first value

Comment: this is not problem. problem is that the changes remain for next query

Comment: Then you need to save whatever changes you have made. The example you have does not iterate through each item, only returns the 1st item on every iteration of the for loop.  (I should have put a i+1 in the example (now amended))

Comment: i have a table contains bookmarking sites. whit a url name fild. the value in the fied is like this: digg.com/submit?phase=2&url={url}&title={title}. I want change the {url} and {title} for each post whit my post url and title. and disply it in nested ListView. but this problem Happens.

Comment: Not sure i still have this right but is this more along lines your after, refer edited above and added? Just refer to the logic as i have no idea your repository and its usage

Comment: can this proble occur by structuremap?

Comment: Never used Structurmap could comment on it sorry

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
post.Title = "test"+i.ToString();
```

you *change* the title of the post in your repository. Thus, this value is read in subsequent iterations. Remember that variable `post` does not contain a *copy* of the value in the repository; it is a *reference* to the *current value* in the repository.

This is what happens in detail:

Iteration 0:

```
post = value 1 from repository (Title = "what is in database")
txtTest.Text = "what is in database"
post.Title = "test0" (changes the value in the repository!)
```

Iteration 1:

```
post = value 1 from repository (Title = "test0")
txtTest.Text = "test0"
post.Title = "test1" (changes the value in the repository!)
```

Iteration 2:

```
post = value 1 from repository (Title = "test1")
txtTest.Text = "test1"
post.Title = "test2" (changes the value in the repository!)
```

Comment: @user806160: Don't change post.Title.

Comment: @user806160: Don't change post.Title. ;-) If you explain to me, *why* you change post.Title, I might be able to suggest a different solution.

Comment: @Tavakoli: That doesn't really help. Let me ask more directly: Why exactly did you write the line: `post.Title = "test"+i.ToString();`?

Comment: @Heinzi:i have a table contains bookmarking sites. whit a url name fild.  the value in the fied is like this: http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&url={url}&title={title}. I want change the {url} and {title} for each post whit my post url and title. and disply it in nested ListView. but this problem Happens.

Comment: @Tavakoli: OK, this is getting a bit complicated. I suggest that you edit your question and clearly state: (A) What is in your database initially, (b) what is the output you want to see on the web page, (c) how do you want the values in your database to change while showing the web page.

Comment: can this proble occur by structuremap